# Elmah MVC Could not load file or assembly Elmah.SqlServer

Tags: model-view-controller, elmah

I installed elmah.mvc.2.1.2 from the nuget package manage console. I ran the script `ELMAH-1.2-db-SQLServer.sql` to modify the database.

To the `configuration` section of `web.config` I added

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah.SqlServer" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
</elmah>
```

I know that `DefaultConnection` works for everything else we do in the app.

I have programmed an action `/Home/TestError` that throws an error. The error is thrown but no entry is made in the database. When I navigate to `/elmah` I get the error `Could not load file or assembly 'Elmah.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies.`

I reinstalled Elmah from package manager console but it made no difference. There is no `Elmah.SqlServer` in the bin folder so I cannot add the reference manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlErrorLog is located in the Elmah assembly (not Elmah.SqlServer). Try the following:

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
</elmah>
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasArdal. That's just the ticket.

Comment: No problem @Vague :) I'm working on an ELMAH config validator, but for now, IntelliSense for this kind of config will help you: http://blog.elmah.io/the-elmah-schema/